# Any NFC readers (Android or iOS) able to access the ePassport raw (still encrypted) data e.g. without the Basic Access Control (BAC)?

Tags: privacy, android, ios, nfc

Firstly, I assume it's possible to passively read the encrypted data from a ePassport NFC chip?

All of the NFC scanning apps fail to load anything without the BAC. We are not interested in the encrypted data and don't require the BAC.

One app allows you to enter/or scan the BAC (DOB, Exp Date, and Name) to gain access to the full biometric data. But this is not our interest. We just are interesed if the raw encrypted data can be scanned. Primairly for maintaining privacy.

Is that possible? Is there a raw scanning iOS app that can do this?